# How can I log all "Caused by" exceptions with log4j2 (json)?

Tags: java, log4j2

[Log4j2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) offers the `exception` and `exceptionRootCause` event template resolvers. However, these only access the top-level and bottom-level exception.

So when I have this

```
Throwable a = new RuntimeException("a");
Throwable b = new RuntimeException("b", a);
Throwable c = new RuntimeException("c", b);
log.error("Exception", c);
```

I only see `a` and `c`, but I have no way to see anything in-between. Java natively supports this with `c.printStackTrace();`.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: c
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: b
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: a
```

How can I get this information in log4j?

My config:

```
{
  "exception": {
    "class_name": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "className"
    },
    "message": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "message"
    },
    "cause": {
      "class_name": {
        "$resolver": "exceptionRootCause",
        "field": "className"
      },
      "message": {
        "$resolver": "exceptionRootCause",
        "field": "message"
      },
      "stack_trace": {
        "$resolver": "exceptionRootCause",
        "field": "stackTrace",
        "stackTrace": {
          "elementTemplate": {
            "class_name": {
              "$resolver": "stackTraceElement",
              "field": "className"
            },
            "method": {
              "$resolver": "stackTraceElement",
              "field": "methodName"
            },
            "file": {
              "$resolver": "stackTraceElement",
              "field": "fileName"
            },
            "line": {
              "$resolver": "stackTraceElement",
              "field": "lineNumber"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "line": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "lineNumber"
  },
  "class_name": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "className"
  },
  "@version": 1,
  "source_host": "${hostName}",
  "message": {
    "$resolver": "message"
  },
  "thread_name": {
    "$resolver": "thread",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "@timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp"
  },
  "level": {
    "$resolver": "level",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "file": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "fileName"
  },
  "method": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "methodName"
  },
  "logger_name": {
    "$resolver": "logger",
    "field": "name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt seem reproducible to me. I can see `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: b` and `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: a` but it seems that the logger has hidden a lot of the duplicate details. Is your issue that you do not see `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: b`?

Comment: Though it might be because I am using Slf4j as a facade for log4j2. Can you show your output from log4j2?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X {"exception":{"class_name":"java.lang.RuntimeException","message":"c","cause":{"class_name":"java.lang.RuntimeException","message":"a","stack_trace":[{"class_name":"...","method":"main","file":"....java","line":258}]}}}

Comment: @experimentunit1998X also added my config

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you wanted the logs as JSON. I attempted to output it as JSON, although I can still get all the intermediate causes, it is in a different format (JSON format is like cause: { some object here } )

Comment: The config I used is the default log4j2.xml and defined a RollingFileAppender. Then I defined a Logger that uses this RollingFileAppender. I didnt use exception or exception root cause I am afraid. i just used a logger and logged it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of `JsonTemplateLayout`. Stack trace resolution using objects (that is, not-`stringified`) is performed by `StackTraceObjectResolver`. There you can see only `throwable.getStackTrace()` is used, that is, the causal chain is not traversed. I see a couple of options you can take:

1. You can implement your own resolver. There is [extensive documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html#extending) on the subject.
2. You can contribute this as a feature to the project. I strongly recommend you to start with a PR discussing the idea before writing any line of code first.
3. You can also sponsor one of the maintainers to develop this. See [the support page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/support.html#sponsorship) for details.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of JTL.

Comment: Thank you! It isn't a must-have, just nice for manual debugging. So `"stackTrace":{"stringified":true}` is good enough, just wanted to make sure I am not missing a native feature similar to the root-cause. Good work on JTL

Comment: @user6412004, what do you use for log storage? Where do you eventually keep your logs and how do you navigate through them?

Answer (score -1):

I can offer you a feature that extracts stacktrace as a `String`. So instead of doing

```
log.error("Exception", c);
```

you can do

```
log.error("Exception {}", TextUtils.getStacktrace(c));
```

or

```
log.error("Exception " + TextUtils.getStacktrace(c));
```

`TextUtils` class comes as part of the MgntUtils Open Source Java library written and maintained by me. Method `getStacktrace()` can extract Stacktrace as a `String` in full or smartly filtered format. You can see the details in [TextUtils Javadoc](https://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html). The library itself could be found on [Maven Central as Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (packaged as a jar file, and, source code and Javadoc provided separately)

Comment: The author is asking for rendering the stack trace as an object, not string. Plus, stringified stack trace rendering including the causal chain is already supported by Log4j and `JsonTemplateLayout`.